# PHP end point conversion to java

Tags: php, rest, endpoint

this might be silly to ask but im kinda stuck
I'm working with APIs that I believe that are written in PHP and I got the following

API URL ​- ​ ​http://url:port/api/api.php   -  Action1  - Post Request

```
$post_data = array(  'field1' => 'value1', 

                     'field2' => 'value2',

                     'field3' => array(  'field11' => 'value11',
                                         'field12' => 'value12',  
                                       )  
                );
```

I was wondering how the array would be converted to the URL parameters

I've been trying version of the below to test but I cant seem to get it right

http://url:port/api/api.php?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=field11=value11&field12=value12

(Sorry if I didnt use fully technical language)

Comment: If its called a `Post Request` it is likely expecting data to be POSTed and not sent on the querystring

Comment: as a request body? the issue is that I can't seem to build the endpoint in java. Im trying to use a RestTemplate in java to call that API but i cant get the body or the parameters right

Answer (score 0):

When I'm trying to work out the syntax of a post request I normally work out the logistics of the process with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).  Once you have the command working you can extract the code snippet.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\r\n    \"namespace\": \"something\",\r\n    \"user\": \"del-user-1\"\r\n} ");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://10.10.10.10:4443/object/users")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("x-sds-auth-token", "xxx")
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "xxxxxxx")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: thats what im trying to do. I cant seem to get neither the query params nor the request body done...

Comment: can't seem to get any conclusion out of that :(

Comment: Are you looking for a php solution or something in another language?